# Do we have to declare variable within try block or outside the try block?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best practice/recommendation to declare and use the variable with try/catch/finally ?.

do we have to declare the variable out side of the try block and dispose on the finally ? or declare within try block and get dispose automatically ?

```
string Name = String.Empty;
try
{
    //do work
}
catch
{
   //safely access s
   Console.WriteLine(Name);
}

OR

string Name;
try
{
    //do work
}
catch
{
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
   {
       //safely access s
       Console.WriteLine(Name);
   }
}
```

Comment: It depends entirely on what variable and what work...

Comment: Why do you expect a variable to be disposed automatically by a `try...catch` block?

Comment: Your second example won't compile since `Name` is not definitely assigned before being read in the catch block. That aside, you should give variables the smallest scope possible.

Comment: Declare it where you need it. What you mean however is "initialize" rather than "declare".

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the scope you need and what you want to do with the variable. If you declare it within the `try` block, you will not be able to use the variable outside the `block`, not even within the `catch` block. This has to do with the fact that `catch` has to handle an exceptional circumstance and `finally` should always be able to execute. When you declare your variable inside the `try` scope, you don't know if it has been initialized when the exception is thrown. And you never know if the variable is ever initialized after your `try/catch` block. Therefore, if you want to use a variable inside the catch/finally or later in the code, you can better be safe and declare it before (that way you are always sure you can handle the disposing in the finally block). But, always try to give your variable the smallest scope possible. So if you are sure you won't need it outside the `try` scope, declare it inside the `try`.

An example of what I meant:

```
try
{
    throw new SomeException("It goes wrong here");
    string iNeedThisVariable = "but i never get initialized";
}
catch (SomeException e)
{  
    Console.Out.WriteLine(iNeedThisVariable); //This goes wrong, since you need to show the string, but it has never been initialized
}
finally
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(iNeedThisVariable); //Also can't use it here!
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Really useful and answering questions most devs ask themselves all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of variable is,

If it is any com component like connection, dataReader, filestream handle and you think the objects needs to be closed manually you should declare them outside of try and dispose them in finally.

If you have normal types of variables like you mentioned string it will be destroyed automatically no need to dispose them.

Better way to dispose COM components is to use using like this.

```
using(var test = new Object())
{//Do Coding here
}
```